# Android: Why is there extra padding on my screen?

Tags: android, android-layout

It works fine on Android 4.0, but on 2.3 there is extra padding around the entire screen. It seems like it thinks the screen is smaller than it is. I'm using 4.0.3 to compile it.

I'm developing an app.

[image]

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.yolo"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name="Categories"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="Main">
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:text="Where are you?"
            />
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/mall"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="At the mall"
            android:onClick="selectCategory"/>
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/home"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/mall"
            android:text="At home"
            android:onClick="selectCategory"/>
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/store"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/mall"
            android:text="At a store"
            android:onClick="selectCategory"/>
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/downtown"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/home"
            android:text="Downtown"
            android:onClick="selectCategory"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post a screenshot of the issue. Also post up your AndroidManifest.xml file. It is most likely a problem with your manifest.

Comment: Please post your layout file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give more detail. But it might be related with possible modifications made by the developer of the particular Android system.

Comment: There aren't any more details to give.

Comment: For a start, what do you mean by "the entire screen"? Does the status bar also not aligned with the actual physical boundaries of your display?